# Filter multiple criteria from Range vba

Tags: vba, excel, filter, criteria

I have list of 34 Itemcodes, which start all the time

> (example:  FRP-BN* FRP-CD* FRP-CL* FRP-IS* NLP-FL* NLP-BR* NLP-FL*
>   NLP-IS*)

Now I want to filter Worksheet B after these criteria, The ID's there are longer, like this FRP-BN32746238 for example and there can be many in it. I want to get all

I tried this

```
Sub Filter3()

Dim lastRow1 As Long
lastRow1 = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim lastRow2 As Long
lastRow2 = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim vCrit As Variant
Dim wsL As Worksheet
Dim rngCrit As Range


Set wsL = Worksheets("Legend")
Set rngCrit = wsL.Range("I5:I7")

vCrit = rngCrit.Value


Range("K5").Formula = vCrit
Sheets("DataSheetFR").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(vCrit), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

My Criteria list is in I5 to I35 or something, and it works if I only put in I5:I6 so with 2 different one but as soon it  come to more than 2 it fails and only gives me a blank list.

How Can I do it? Please help me

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce this. It works fine for me.

Comment: If you use wildcards in your criteria, it will only work for two values. You would have to use an Advanced filter instead - which should be simple since you already have the list of values in a range (just remove the asterisks since advanced filter uses 'begins with' by default).

Comment: Hej Rory, even a normal advanced filter apart from the macro only gives me an empty list, again and again